# Why do Pil_to_image() and read_image() functions give me different tensors?

Tags: image-processing, deep-learning, pytorch, python-imaging-library, torchvision

So I have an [image](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/k9mw4pox9bpk6bsskyd3i/image.jpg?rlkey=vr3yjh9y8x1dsmksgvtw6gi2l&dl=0) in JPG format and I read this image as a tensor using two different ways:

1. with

```
from torchvision.io import read_image

read_image(image_path)
```

and it gives me the tensor:

```
tensor([[[255, 255, 255,  ..., 191, 191, 191],
         [255, 255, 255,  ..., 191, 191, 191],
         [255, 255, 255,  ..., 191, 191, 191],
         ...,
         [255, 255, 255,  ..., 191, 191, 191],
         [255, 255, 255,  ..., 191, 191, 191],
         [255, 255, 255,  ..., 191, 191, 191]],

        [[255, 255, 255,  ..., 255, 255, 255],
         [255, 255, 255,  ..., 255, 255, 255],
         [255, 255, 255,  ..., 255, 255, 255],
         ...,
         [255, 255, 255,  ..., 255, 255, 255],
         [255, 255, 255,  ..., 255, 255, 255],
         [255, 255, 255,  ..., 255, 255, 255]],

        [[255, 255, 255,  ..., 255, 255, 255],
         [255, 255, 255,  ..., 255, 255, 255],
         [255, 255, 255,  ..., 255, 255, 255],
         ...,
         [255, 255, 255,  ..., 255, 255, 255],
         [255, 255, 255,  ..., 255, 255, 255],
         [255, 255, 255,  ..., 255, 255, 255]],

        [[129, 143, 143,  ..., 255, 255, 255],
         [143, 255, 254,  ..., 255, 255, 255],
         [143, 254, 255,  ..., 255, 255, 255],
         ...,
         [143, 255, 255,  ..., 255, 255, 255],
         [144, 254, 255,  ..., 255, 255, 255],
         [129, 144, 143,  ..., 255, 255, 255]]], dtype=torch.uint8)
```

2. when I use

```
from torchvision.transforms.functional import pil_to_tensor

img = PIL.Image.open(image_path) 
pil_to_tensor(img)
```

it gives me the tensor

```
tensor([[[  0,   0,   0,  ...,  64,  64,  64],
         [  0,   0,   0,  ...,  64,  64,  64],
         [  0,   0,   0,  ...,  64,  64,  64],
         ...,
         [  0,   0,   0,  ...,  64,  64,  64],
         [  0,   0,   0,  ...,  64,  64,  64],
         [  0,   0,   0,  ...,  64,  64,  64]],

        [[  0,   0,   0,  ...,   0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0,  ...,   0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0,  ...,   0,   0,   0],
         ...,
         [  0,   0,   0,  ...,   0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0,  ...,   0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0,  ...,   0,   0,   0]],

        [[  0,   0,   0,  ...,   0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0,  ...,   0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0,  ...,   0,   0,   0],
         ...,
         [  0,   0,   0,  ...,   0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0,  ...,   0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0,  ...,   0,   0,   0]],

        [[126, 112, 112,  ...,   0,   0,   0],
         [112,   0,   1,  ...,   0,   0,   0],
         [112,   1,   0,  ...,   0,   0,   0],
         ...,
         [112,   0,   0,  ...,   0,   0,   0],
         [111,   1,   0,  ...,   0,   0,   0],
         [126, 111, 112,  ...,   0,   0,   0]]], dtype=torch.uint8)
```

I get the correct and the original image when I use the first tensor not the second one.
Also I observed that I can get the second tensor by subtracting each value in the first tensor from 255.
Then my questions are:

1. Why does the second way invert the original image?
2. If I use the conversion formula `255 + second_tensor = first_tensor`, do I always get the right result?

Thanks!

Comment: No, PIL doesn’t typically invert the image just for fun. What is `image_path`? Maybe something about the image file makes PIL think it needs to invert the pixel data?

Comment: the image lies just in a dir in my home folder `'~/energylabel_backend/images/train/images/4dac992c-182be687a44da51ef074631fe11901f8.jpg'`. Another thing when I say `pil_to_tensor(img).shape` I get `torch.Size([4, 2268, 1252])` which is not the case in the first way.

Comment: You didn't share your image so it's hard to say which is correct, or what's odd about your image. Maybe it has a colour-profile attached. If you plan to share it, maybe use Google Drive or Dropbox or something that doesn't alter it.

Comment: @MarkSetchell here is the link to the image https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/k9mw4pox9bpk6bsskyd3i/image.jpg?rlkey=vr3yjh9y8x1dsmksgvtw6gi2l&dl=0

Comment: Your image is in (somewhat rare in JPEG) CMYK. PIL seems to have understood it completely but the conversion to tensor looks incorrect. I would suggest you have PIL convert it to `RGB` before conversion to tensor and see if `torchvision` gets that right. So change to `img = PIL.Image.open(image_path).convert('RGB')`. There's no loss of generalisation or accuracy so you could do that always, or if you want to be conservative, only convert to `RGB` if originally `CMYK` so `if im.mode == 'CMYK': im = im.convert('RGB')`